# Installing Python 3.8 on windows 7 32bit with SP1

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, python-3.8

I can't install Python 3.8 on windows 7 32 bit with SP1 error Log says `detected windows 7 sp1 without kb2533625` and I searched for this update all day but found nothing any Help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is typo from Python Developers the update is **kb2533623** not **kb2533625**
and you can download it from [**here**](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/D/7/2D78D0DD-2802-41F5-88D6-DC1D559F206D/Windows6.1-KB2533623-x86.msu) then restart your machine and try to install python 3.8 or 3.7 it will work like a charm

Update As @ClassicOcean said the update for kb2533623 no longer available you can now install this update to solve the problem
[KB3063858](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47409)

Comment: You have saved my day!

Comment: It seems KB2533623 is superseded by KB3063858, https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/20459 ( Its related to .NET Core update )

Answer (score 4):

To install Python 3.7 or 3.8, in windows 7 operating system, you need to install **Windows 7 Service Pack 1** first and then **Update for Windows 7 (KB2533623)** (if not installed already).

Your system is **missing** the **Update for Windows 7 (KB2533623)**, hence in your Python  installation log file it is showing `detected windows 7 sp1 without kb2533625`, although it should have been `detected windows 7 sp1 without KB2533623`, I think this is a mistake from Python developers.

Go to: `My Computer -> Properties` and check the **System Type**. If it is 64-bit Operating System:

1. For **Windows 7 Service Pack 1**, download the file **windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe** from [Windows7 Service Pack-1 download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=5842)
2. For **Update for Windows 7 (KB2533623)**, download it from [this link of Microsoft's official website](https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/0/F106E158-89A1-41E3-A9B5-32FEB2A99A0B/Windows6.1-KB2533623-x64.msu)

If your OS is 32-bit:

1. For **Windows 7 Service Pack 1**, download the file **windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe** from [Windows7 Service Pack-1 download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=5842)
2. For **Update for Windows 7 (KB2533623)**, download it from [this link of Microsoft's official website](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/D/7/2D78D0DD-2802-41F5-88D6-DC1D559F206D/Windows6.1-KB2533623-x86.msu)