# Can't install python-3.7.7 on win 7

Tags: python-3.x

When I try to install python-3.7.7
It says: 
one or more issues caused the setup to fail, please fix this issue...etc.

And below that it says that it needs windows 7 service pack 1.
Problem is I already have it. It shows up in windows edition.

I even tried to reinstall it, thinking that the file I got from microsoft might give me the ability to repair or that I'm missing something. But I can't install it because I already have it.

Below is the logfile which has: KB2533623 update is required to continue.
I'm no expert but I though to actually just download "KB2533623"
When I try to run it it says "The update is not applicable to your computer"
So I even tried looking online for a fix for that but even that did not work.

So I really have no idea how to proceed.

Just in case it might help.
I had an old Python installation.
I tried to reinstall it but no avail, and typing python in the command line showed nothing so it was not installed.

All this so I can have python, 3.4 or more, so I can get pycharm working.
Anyway what can I do now to get a python up and running?

The Python install logfile
[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i001: Burn v3.11.1.2318, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Windows\Temp{0E8F56D2-C72A-44CE-8CEB-C519A68C32E2}.cr\python-3.7.7.exe

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'ShortVersion' to value '3.7'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ShortVersionNoDot' to value '37'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVer' to value '3.7-32'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVerNoDot' to value '37-32'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallAllUsers' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsers' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDir' to value ''

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultAllUsersTargetDir' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]Python[WinVerNoDot]'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetPlatform' to value 'x86'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultJustForMeTargetDir' to value '[LocalAppDataFolder]Programs\Python\Python[WinVerNoDot]'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'OptionalFeaturesRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore[WinVer]\InstalledFeatures'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore[WinVer]\InstallPath'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultCustomTargetDir' to value ''

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomInstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value '[InstallLauncherAllUsersState]'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirState' to value 'enabled'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomBrowseButtonState' to value 'enabled'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_core' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_exe' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_dev' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_lib' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_test' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_doc' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tools' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tcltk' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_pip' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_launcher' to value '-1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'Include_launcherState' to value 'enabled'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_symbols' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_debug' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'LauncherOnly' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedLauncher' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedOldLauncher' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'AssociateFiles' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Shortcuts' to value '1'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrependPath' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'CompileAll' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SimpleInstall' to value '0'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Initializing string variable 'SimpleInstallDescription' to value ''

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=G:\D Drive\Progs\python-3.7.7.exe" -burn.filehandle.attached=272 -burn.filehandle.self=280'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'G:\D Drive\Progs\python-3.7.7.exe'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'G:\D Drive\Progs\'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Aurlian\AppData\Local\Temp\Python 3.7.7 (32-bit)_20200429231308.log'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Python 3.7.7 (32-bit)'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Python Software Foundation'

[1C88:178C][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting numeric variable 'CRTInstalled' to value 1

[1C88:1898][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Did not find G:\D Drive\Progs\unattend.xml

[1C88:1898][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'

[1C88:1898][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'

[1C88:1898][2020-04-29T23:13:08]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '3.7.7150.0'

[1C88:1898][2020-04-29T23:13:08]e000: Detected Windows 7 SP1 without KB2533623

[1C88:1898][2020-04-29T23:13:08]e000: KB2533623 update is required to continue.

Comment: I don”t know if this is true but I heard python 3 isnt available for windows 7.

Comment: I'm sure it's not true.
I had it installed before and had pycharm and did some basic stuff in pycharm without a problem. I'm even installing that version, which is a bit older, just to perfectly match the course I'm doing and also because it worked before.
And it was the same exact copy of windows 7. 
So this is really bothering me

Answer (score 1):

You should install KB2533623 update as it described in your logs.

`[1C88:1898][2020-04-29T23:13:08]e000: KB2533623 update is required to continue.`

Comment: "Below is the logfile which has: KB2533623 update is required to continue. I'm no expert but I though to actually just download "KB2533623" When I try to run it it says "The update is not applicable to your computer" So I even tried looking online for a fix for that but even that did not work."

Answer (score 1):

I would have just added my post as a comment, but my reputation is to low.

It seems that you are right and you need to install SP1 and KB2533623 manually. 
Here is a really good explanation -> [Installing Python 3.8 on windows 7 32bit with SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548069/installing-python-3-8-on-windows-7-32bit-with-sp1)

Comment: Again just the question please.

Answer (score 0):

May be you dowload wrong KB2533623 edition.
It has KB2533623-x86 (32bit) and KB2533623-x64 (64bit).
You can seach "KB2533623-x64"and download it.